# Ajax error without error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax script who use jquery and look like that :

```
$('#myButton').click(function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url : "sqlScript.php",
            type : 'POST',
            data : '',
            dataType : 'html',
            beforeSend : function(newRequest,opts)    
            {           
                $('#myButton').attr("disabled", "disabled");
            },
            success : function(code_html, statut)
            {
                location.reload();
            },
            error : function(resultat, statut, erreur)
            {
                alert('error')
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    })
```

And in my sqlScript.php i have nothing like that :

```
require_once('bdd.php');

$req= $bdd->query("UPDATE ".$table1
                              ." JOIN ".$table2
                              ." ON ".$table1.".".$field1." = ".$table2.".".$field1
                              ." AND ".$table1.".".$field2." = ".$table2.".".$field2
                              ." SET ".$table2.".".$field3." = ".$table2.".".$field3
                           );
echo "OK";
```

And each time i click on the button with id 'myButton' the ajax launch the script but at the end of the script it don't pass in the success but in the error and i don't don't why. More weird : their is no error, i mean the script finish well and my UPDATE is completly done.

But this UPDATE is really long something like 10 minutes ... so peraphs it's because of that.

======== EDIT ========

In bdd.php i only have the define of my database :

```
$host = "localhost";
$db_name = "db";
$user = "root";
$password = "";

try
{
   $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$db_name.';charset=latin1', $user, $password);
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}

$table1 = 'table1';
$table2 = 'table2';
$field1 = 'field1';
$field2 = 'field2';
$field3 = 'field3';
```

Comment: use `console.log()` to show the results of you error variables: `resultat, statut, erreur`. Then show us what error messages you see.

Comment: where are your `$table*` `$field*` variables defined?

Comment: show the code inside `bdd.php`

Comment: your php echo's `OK`,  but your `$.ajax()::success()` does not alert/echo the returned value but does a `location.reload();`

Comment: I agree with @Sean. In order to debug this problem remove your `location.reload()` or else you will always reload the page without seeing the errors.

Comment: i put of the location.reload for the test and i post the result of each variable when my script finish.

Comment: If the scipt take so long I'd guess there is some issue with timeout. Have you tried to [increase timeout](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) in your PHP script?   What happen if you open the script url directly in your browser?

Comment: I didn't see but i have this error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

And the log is  :resu : [object Object];statut : error;erreur : Internal Server Error

Comment: It was that ... i feel so stupid to don't think about it i just add set_time_limit(0); in my file sqlScript.php and it's work thank

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem of timeout just add this line set_time_limit(0); and it's work.